# Stitching different IDs into one Unique ID

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have this kind of data where I have chronological logs of visitors' devices and users. Here you can see that the same person used devices 'abc' and 'def' and has two different user IDs '123' and '456'. We can tell it's the same person because they have at least 2 users on 1 device (or depending how you see it 2 devices with 1 user). User '789' however is another person on their own as far as we can tell

```
+-------+------------+---------+
| date  | device ID  | user ID |
+-------+------------+---------+
| 2 Feb | abc        | 123     |
+-------+------------+---------+
| 3 Feb | abc        | 456     |
+-------+------------+---------+
| 4 Feb | def        | 456     |
+-------+------------+---------+
| 4 Feb | ghj        | 789     |
+-------+------------+---------+
```

I'm trying to stitch them back by assigning the person's very first (chronological) user ID.

What I'm trying to achieve is this:

```
+-------------+------------+------------+
| stitched ID | devices    | users      |
+-------------+------------+------------+
| 123         | [abc, def] | [123, 456] |
+-------------+------------+------------+
| 789         | [ghj]      | [789]      |
+-------------+------------+------------+
```

How do I build the query?

Comment: Are you using Postgres or BigQuery?  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: Google BigQuery and Postgres are two **very** different products. Which one are you really using?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know bigquery but in relational 'style' you should:

1> group by the 'common' attributes,

2> get the 'min' of the id as 'unique-id',

3> I'll also add a new view where for each 'unique' key you add the 'duplicated' ones as storing them as string may get heavy while querying.

Sorry for non-code answer but this should show you the way.